# How to sign a microsoft office or openOffice certificate with a p12 or pfx certificate

Tags: openssl, certificate, ms-office, sign, openoffice.org

I want to be able to sign a Microsoft office or OpenOfiice document with with a digital certificate without using the Gui softwares.

I already signed PDF and XML (with xml-dsig). Some people say I can sign an office document using the xml-dsig method. But I saved a Microsoft word `.docx` file and the content of the file is binary, not XML.

I want to sign the office documents to behave exactly as the signed PDF do. After signing the document, The Microsoft office or the OpenOffice software can read the certificate and validate that the document is signed by a certificate.

I want to be able to do that in Php, Python, Java or ASP.net core.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. From Microsoft word I can sign the document. Microsoft has this feature. How to do that in programming?

Comment: I doesn't necessarily to be Microsoft office. If it's possible to sign the document in OpenOffice programming, no problem.